# Passing parameter to invoked event handler, i.e. element.onchange(); javascript

Tags: javascript, events, parameters, handler

I have a function like this:

```
function doSomething()
{
  // do something with select element
}

document.getElementById("selectel").onchange = doSomething;

// Call onchange event
document.getElementById("selectel").onchange();
```

Now, I recognize that I could call the function directly and pass a parameter.  But I'd like to know if it's possible to pass a parameter to the **onchange()** event handler after it's evoked.  I tried

```
document.getElementById("selectel").onchange("hello");
```

, but this didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to tell us what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Nicolae: It's not always about solving the problem at hand. OP wants to bind an argument to a callback function. A possible scenario is that OP is using the same handler for two elements, and would like to specify a different argument for each.

Comment: Thank you both.  Yes, that could be one scenario.  However, the issue at hand is I have invoked an event handler and it seemed logical that you could place a parameter between the parentheses.  I mean, it seems silly and confusing that the powers-that-be came up with a syntax where you call an event (i.e. onchange()), yet you can't pass parameters to it.  If that is not the intent, then the syntax to call an event should be just "onchange" to avoid confusion.  I apologize for my rant but it seems illogical to me.

Comment: When you add () after a function name, you're calling that function immediately. But you really want to set a function reference to a property of an HTML element that will be called later. You usually do not invoke handlers yourself, the browser calls them for you. Your suggested syntax doesn't make sense if you think about it.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, you are correct.  I made a mistake.  The () call the function immediately.  I understand I can set parameters when setting the reference. I thought that I could "piggyback" more parameters during the function call.  If I can call foobar(1,2,3), it seems logical that I could call onchange(1,2,3).  IMHO, I think it's confusing that an event handler call does not accept parameters.  But your suggestion below is marvelous and I sincerely appreciate your wisdom and generous support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind a parameter to your function. I'm going to copy paste a function from Ext-JS that lets you do just that. **Warning**: not for beginners

```
/**
 * Create a new function from the provided <code>fn</code>, change <code>this</code> to the provided scope, optionally
 * overrides arguments for the call. (Defaults to the arguments passed by the caller)
 *
 * @param {Function} fn The function to delegate.
 * @param {Object} scope (optional) The scope (<code><b>this</b></code> reference) in which the function is executed.
 * <b>If omitted, defaults to the browser window.</b>
 * @param {Array} args (optional) Overrides arguments for the call. (Defaults to the arguments passed by the caller)
 * @param {Boolean/Number} appendArgs (optional) if True args are appended to call args instead of overriding,
 * if a number the args are inserted at the specified position
 * @return {Function} The new function
 */
function bind(fn, scope, args, appendArgs) {
    var method = fn,
        applyArgs;

    return function() {
        var callArgs = args || arguments;

        if (appendArgs === true) {
            callArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
            callArgs = callArgs.concat(args);
        }
        else if (typeof appendArgs == 'number') {
            callArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); // copy arguments first
            applyArgs = [appendArgs, 0].concat(args); // create method call params
            Array.prototype.splice.apply(callArgs, applyArgs); // splice them in
        }

        return method.apply(scope || window, callArgs);
    };
}
```

You can use it like

```
function onChange(e, customParameter) {
  // Whatever code
}

document.getElementById("selectel").onchange = bind(onChange, null, ["customParameter"], true);
```

When your handler is called, additional parameters are appended to the arguments passed by the event handler (the event object).

There's a lot of meat in this function, so feel free to ask any additional questions.

Here's a jsfiddle to see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/yBhG6/

Comment: Thank you again.  Yes, this looks very good.  Very, very good.  I thought addEventListener and attachEvent may have been a good alternative, but that did not resolve the original issue (even though they are richer than the DOM 0 version).

Comment: @Andrew Newer browsers have https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind which is a lot like the function above

Comment: @JuanMendes How widely supported is it though?  Back through How many browsers.  In my current context, I need to support through IE 7.

Comment: @Andrew That page has a browser compatibility section, IE 7 is not supported, IE9 is the first supported version for IE. I just wanted to point out that this is now part of the language itself, but most people still use some shim like the one I listed above

Answer (score 4):

Declare an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("selectel").onchange = function() { doSomething("hello"); }
```

Comment: That's definitely the easiest way, but you need to pass the parameters that were passed to onchange to the callback. I'm posting a more generalized version

Comment: Thank you.  Yes this does work, but it has a side-effect of making "this" defined as the global object (ie. window), not the element targeted.

Comment: I think, this might be solved with using jQuery event handlers as well as getting the object inside handler function

Comment: to fix the side effect you mentioned (and the missing event parameter), you can just do `function(e) {doDomething.call(this, e}};`

Comment: Thank you, both.  I appreciate both of your suggestions.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, you can use `$('#el').bind('change', {customData:'whatever'}, myHandler)`. The object you pass to the find function will be passed back to your callback. See http://api.jquery.com/bind/, under the Passing Event Data header

Answer (score 1):

You could use the apply() method which lets you pass arguments.

```
doSomething.apply(document.getElementById("selectel"), "hello");
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this before and it invoked the function immediately.  Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two approach to this question.

One is to call Your callback directly by passing `select` as `this`:

```
doSomething.apply(document.getElementById("selectel"), "Hello");
```

Second is similar to Igor's, but with help of other variables:

```
var param = "foo"; // Whatever default is
document.getElementById("selectel").onchange = function() {
    doSomething(param);
} 

param = "hello";
document.getElementById("selectel").onchange();
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's an interesting idea.  In theory, this could be expanded: Put the variables and function inside an object and manipulate the object, avoiding global variables.

Comment: If you do that, then it becomes the same as Igor's answer.